# Facebook fb.ui dialog no popup on Safari

Tags: facebook, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk

It works fine on Firefox, Chrome and IE, but no pop up on safari and no exception and error.
Tested several safaris on different machines. Safari block pop ups by default. is there any way to unblock it automatically?

```
shareButton.on('click', function(e) {
    // do something
    shareAction();
}

function shareAction() {
    // do something
    share();
}

function share() {
    // do something
    submitShare();
}

function submitShare() {
    // do something
    // use the default fb.ui settings
    FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
    },
    function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
}
```

Comment: are u using any cookies? in the code it doesn't seem like. I was developing a FB app and it gave some trouble because of cookies. try cookie false when initializing facebook sdk

Comment: or may be the pop up is blocked by safari browser.